# How to add session spring mvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc

How to add session spring mvc my intention is  i have login email and password and get the all details of that person like id ,emai,gender like and i place in session when ever i call id that id will be added like that remaining all

```
  @Controller
  //@Scope("session")
  @SessionAttributes("admin")
  //@RequestMapping("admin")
  public class AdminController {
@Autowired
private EmployeeService employeeService;

@Autowired
private EmployeeCredentialsService employeeCredentialsService;



@RequestMapping(value="adminLogin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showForm(Map model) {
  AdminBean adminBean = new AdminBean();
    model.put("admin", adminBean);

    return "adminLogin";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/adminLogin", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String adminLogin(@Valid AdminBean adminBean, BindingResult result,  Map model,HttpSession session){
  if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "adminLogin";
    }
  boolean userExists = employeeCredentialsService.checkLogin(adminBean.getEmail(),adminBean.getPassword());
  System.out.println(userExists);
  if(userExists){
        //model.put("adminBean", adminBean.getEmail());
        //session.setAttribute("adminBean", adminBean);
        return "adminHome";
    }else{
        result.rejectValue("email","invaliduser");
        model.put("invalid", "Invalid Username or Password!! Please try again!!!");
        return "adminLogin";
    }
```

}

```
   //enter code here
     public boolean checkLogin(String email, String password){      
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    boolean userFound = false;      
    //String SQL_QUERY ="select * from Oruganti_admin where admin_user_name='"+email+"' and adminpassword='"+password+"'";
    String SQL_QUERY ="from  AddAdmin as A where A.email=? and A.password=? ";
    Query query = session.createQuery(SQL_QUERY);
    query.setParameter(0,email);
    query.setParameter(1,password);
    List list = query.list();

    if ((list != null) && (list.size() > 0)) {
        userFound= true;
    }

    session.close();
    //System.out.println(userFound);
    return userFound;
```

}

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: how to add session in spring mvc project i am confused ?

Comment: What happened when you remove comment for `session.setAttribute("adminBean", adminBean);`?

Comment: it shows com.dineshonjava.model.AddAdmin@7593e5a8  like this

Comment: Of course, if you are trying to print the object you will get output like that. But if you want to use as `AdminBean` object, you have to cast it to it. Like `AdminBean adminBean = (AdminBean) session.getAttribute("adminBean");` because, `getAttribute()` returns `Object`.

Comment: sir can  u provide any sample program

Comment: Where do you want to read the `adminBean` object? In `jsp` or in `java`?

Comment: in jsp page we can place it

Comment: <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>admin home page</title>
</head>
<body>
welcome to ${adminBean1}
<h4 align="left"><a href="add.html">Registration</a></h4>
<h4 align="left"><a href="employees.html">List of Students</a></h4>


</body>
</html>

Comment: @malli code goes in the question, nicely formatted of course

Comment: @Jack Flamp I can't understand what you say?

Comment: @malli, please edit your question and add the code you have posted in the last comment.

Comment: jsp code? or java code?

Comment: Please check the below answer and see if it is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the values inside the `adminBean` in the HTML page, you can use the JSP's implicit objects. Considering you have a property `adminName` inside the `adminBean1` object, you can print it using `adminBean1.adminName`:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">;
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>admin home page</title>
</head>

<body> welcome to ${adminBean1.adminName}
    <h4 align="left"><a href="add.html">Registration</a></h4>
    <h4 align="left"><a href="employees.html">List of Students</a></h4> </body>

</html>
```

You should replace the property `adminName` with whatever property's value you want to display. That property name should be exactly same as in `AdminBean` class

Comment: I added ${adminBean1.adminName} but its not working.why its not working is there any other problem in my code.

Comment: What is the content of your `AdminBean` class?

Comment: package com.dineshonjava.bean;

public class AdminBean {
 
 private String email; 
 
 private String password;

 public String getEmail() {
  return email;
 }

 public void setEmail(String email) {
  this.email = email;
 }

 public String getPassword() {
  return password;
 }

 public void setPassword(String password) {
  this.password = password;
 }

}

Comment: Add `session.setAttribute("adminBean1", adminBean);` in your controller. Also if you want to display `email` of `AdminBean` object then use `${adminBean1.email}` in your JSP.

Comment: sir its working but it shows email , password but i want id based on this email from database

Comment: What more do you expect mate? We can not give you the whole application. Please try out some tutorials out on the Internet. If you find a specific problem while applying it post another question here. Meanwhile, if your current problem got resolved with my answer please mark it as accepted.